# What does 'failed' mean in the k8s dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

Running a `kubectl get pods` on my deployed application (ONAP), shows that all pods are `Running`. However the Kubernetes dashboard shows that 29 pods failed. So what does failed mean in this context?

Is it the cumulative times that pods failed *before* they then perhaps subsequently ran correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean the number of restarts, in which case, yes, that's what it is.

But if a pod has restarted so many times, you should take a look at it.

Imagine a pod that gradually gets to the limits of its resources (CPU, memory or both), and fails every 2 days. In 2 months your pod will restart 30 times. It might not look like a big deal, but obviously it's not completely healthy.